# Browser control for wxPython that can run java applets

Tags: python, html, user-interface, browser, wxpython

I need to incorporate a small web browser in my wxPython project.

I have tried out the control that ships with wxPython (wx.html module), but it sucks for me. It can't run java applets, CSS, javascript, nothing but html.

Anyone knows of a webbrowser control for wxPython that can at least:

- Parse HTML
- Run java applets
- Return source of a webpage
- Runs on Windows, Mac OSX and linux

Thanks,

bl00dshooter

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wxWebkit](http://wxwebkit.wxcommunity.com/index.php?n=Main.HomePage) - there are bindings available for wxPython. Not too sure on its running of Java apps, though.